# SQL code Compatibility: Migrating an Oracle RDS database to an Athena Trino Datalake

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds, trino

We are thinking of migrating an Oracle RDS database to Athena Trino Datalake.

We would keep all database names, schemas, tables, and columns the same.

Would SQL that runs correctly against the Oracle RDS database be 100% guaranteed to run correctly against the Athena Trina Datalake (with possible trivial differences, such as sorting-order for queries without ORDER BY)?

My guess is that it would not, though hopefully most such SQL would run correctly in both systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Oracle SQL dialect is not the same as the Trino dialect. Trino is aiming to be as close as possible to the ANSI SQL specification.

The specific syntax supported also depends a lot on the versions in use. For example Trino recently got support for [MERGE](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/merge.html) added.

Keep in mind though that Athena is using a very old version of Trino so depending on your needs you might be better off running Trino yourself or using another supported offering such as [Starburst Enterprise](https://docs.starburst.io/starburst-enterprise/index.html) or [Starburst Galaxy](https://docs.starburst.io/starburst-galaxy/index.html).

In general however you will be able to run most queries direct or after minor modifications.